# Read in 2D array file into 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a top-down rpg game and I plan to use txt files and 2D arrays for levels, I am going to have a 2D array containing values from 0 to 6, each representing a different texture, I plan to keep these levels in a txt file, but I am having trouble reading in the file into a 2D array.

This is what my file looks like

```
0000000010000000044444444
0000050010000005504444444
0050000010000000005544444
0005000010000000000550550
0000000011111000333333333
0000000000001111100000000
0005000055000010000000000
0000000000000010000000000
0000050000500010000000000
0000000000000010000000000
0000000050005010000000200
0001111111111112200002000
0501000000000002200002000
0051000000000000000002000
```

This is my code for reading in my array, by the way its 14x25.

```
public int[][] readInLevel(String levelNumber)
    {

        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(levelNumber)));
            while (in.ready() == true)
            {

                for (int row = 0; row <= 13; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = 0; column <= 24; column++)
                    {
                        level_1[row][column] = in.read();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        return null;

    }
```

And this is my 2D array.

```
int level_1[][] = new int[14][25];
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question. What's the problem?

Comment: @chrylis When I read in the array I just get -49 for all the numbers.

Comment: Also, one thing which isn't related to the question: by convention, use "e.printStackTrace()" instead. Usually printing out objects will just print out data about the object, which usually includes pointers and stuff. Unless Exception has a unique toString(), that won't work(but I don't know for sure).

Answer (score 1):

`in.read` reads a an ASCII byte. Notice [here](http://www.asciitable.com/) that "0" in Asciii is 48. So, subtract 48 from in.read, like this: `level_1[row][column]=in.read()-48;` If that doesn't work, then cast to int: `level_1[row][column]=(int)(in.read-48);`

EDIT: Okay, there's one way you can do it which is what I do. 
EDIT EDIT: checking for newlines

```
byte b=0;
int row=0;
int column=0;
while((b=in.read())!=1) {
    if((char)b=='\n') {
        row++;
        column=0;
    } else {
        level_1[row][column]=b-48;
        column++;
    }
}
```

There might be some issues with the row/column code, I didn't think through it thoroughly.

EDIT EDIT EDIT: okay, found the problem. BufferedReader.read() returns -1 if there is no byte, meaning that it returns -49 each time because it return -1-48. That means that your reader isn't properly initialized. Check your file. I usually do:

```
File f=new File(path);
FileReader fr=new FileReader(f);
BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(fr);
```

Okay, here's my code: http://pastebin.com/qstGnK77

It works just fine, look at the output.

Comment: Can I see the rest of your code? You have this function that returns an array, yet you seem to be treating it as a void function.

Comment: Yeah, I switched that back to void. The rest of my code has nothing to do with the array, what I think is causing the problem is its trying to read whole lines at once instead of reading one int at a time. What would be solution  to that?

Comment: That worked a little, some of the numbers made it through. While most are 0.

Comment: Umm, maybe most are 0 because your file is mostly 0s? Also, instead of processing it, try doing System.out.print((char)b); Since it reads character by character, if you don't print out the file exactly as is, you have an error with your bufferedreader.

Comment: No, my file is in my question and only that line of 4's at the top right hand corner is showing.

Comment: Okay, I might know the issue. MS Notepad does \n\r instead of the normal \n. I'll create some code of my own and post it in a bit.

Comment: Since you can't chat, I guess I have to put something else here. Anyway, I posted some code, but it's a quick-and-dirty method and not totally recommended. However, since you're dealing with small strings, in this case, I think that the readability is most important than the efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

Circuit Smasher is correct in that you should subtract 48 the ascii value to get the int that corresponds to the character in your level file.  You're seeing -49 because -1 (read()'s EOF return value) minus 48 is -49.

The restrictions in your `for` loops are confusing to read; perhaps you should consider changing them to

`for (int row = 0; row < 14; row++)`

Then, remember that the 15th character of each row is the newline character.  This is offsetting the grid.  We can get rid of this newline character by reading it.  (You could also just get the first 14 characters from each row of input using the other definition of `BufferedReader.read()`  Or you could use the `Scanner` class which has a function to get an entire line of input.)

The following snippet appears to function correctly (I've added some print statements to ensure validity):

```
   int[][] level_1 = new int[14][25];
   try {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                new FileInputStream("input.txt")));
        while (in.ready() == true) {

            for (int row = 0; row < 14; row++) {
                for (int column = 0; column < 25; column++) {

                    level_1[row][column] = in.read() - 48;
                    System.out.print(level_1[row][column] + ", ");
                }
                in.read(); // this is important

                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Additional edit:  Are you using an IDE?  In Eclipse, the input files need to be in the root directory of the project you're working on.  It may be different for other IDEs.  If you're still receiving a bunch of -49s then I'd think the file isn't being read properly.

Comment: adding on to what he said, try File f=new File("input.txt); then do f.createNewFile(); that will allow you to see where the file is created. Put your file there.

Comment: I had initially added a `new File(filename)` into the `BufferedReader` constructor, but it didn't appear to be necessary; works either way for me.  EDIT: I misread your comment, Circuit Smasher.  That's a good way to figure out where the file is.